# Why TCP packets have a low sequence but high ack number?

Tags: wireshark, tcp

[image: Low TCP sequence num but have a high ack num]

Like the `wireshark` outputs, I captured two TCP packets, one with sequence num 149483 and ack 149453, one with sequence num 149491 and ack 146685.

I think the packet with seq num 149483 is sent first(because it has low sequence num), acked 149453.
Then sent seq num 149491, but here why this packet acked 146685 which already confirmed by the first packets?

Comment: You are only showing one side of the connection, so maybe there was a retransmission between frames 309 and 315?

Answer (score 0):

Both sequence and acknowledgement numbers are sequence numbers, from the perspective of TCP, but you must remember that each side selects a random initial sequence number from the 32-bit space.  In other words, there is no relationship between the sequence and acknowledgement numbers.

The way it works as that hosts A and B establish a connection.  Host A will select a random ISN and send that to B in the initial SYN.  Host B will acknowledge that number (plus 1, by RFC) and select its own random ISN.  Host A will acknowledge that (plus 1, again).  From here on out, the sequence numbers are used in connection with the total amount of data sent in a segment to reassemble the segments according to the sequence numbers, with the sequence numbers effectively being used to track the number of bytes sent in each direction in the TCP connection.

Since this is how it works, it is perfectly fine to have a "low" acknowledgement number with a "high" sequence number.  It's also fine to have pretty much any other combination that you can imagine.

Comment: Note that Wireshark shows relative sequence numbers by default. You can toggle this in the TCP protocol preferences.